# How could I use this PHP time script to schedule a script without cron?

Tags: php, cron, scheduling

I had found a script that supposedly schedules a script to execute. I am very new to PHP and I do NOT want to use cron. Here's the script I found:

```
<?php 
$hour = date('G');
$day  = date('N'); // 1..7 for Monday to Sunday

if (($hour >= 5  && $hour <= 7)  // 5am - 7am
||  ($hour >= 10 && $hour <= 12) // 10am - 12 noon
||  ($hour >= 15 && $hour <= 19) // 3pm - 7pm
||  ($day == 5)                  // Friday
) { ?>
 //my script
<?php } ?>
```

Because I know so little, If I put my script where it says, would it execute at that certain time every time that happens? Thank you in advance! -Ben

Comment: Why not cron? It was made for this.

Comment: Why do you not want to use cron? What you show is a poor replacement for it (because you would need a user to actually trigger the script)

Comment: I'm so new to PHP, I'm not ready for this. It's a simple task. I hoped there was a way to do it with out cron!

Comment: While you'd better cast to int (I'm not sure whether PHP already does that before comparison): `$hour = (int)date('G');`, that script behavior is only to execute code in place of `// my script` only in selected time ranges; this way you still have to manually execute the script (or use cron..), plus it doesn't guarantee code is executed once, etc.. So: using cron is the only reliable way to do this. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: You don't need to be "ready" for anything! It would be like saying "I just learned how to walk, but I'm using only the right leg since I'm not ready to use both"..

Comment: Ok...how do I use cron? what do I do? What do I have to get?

Comment: One reason OP might not want to use cron is because he is not the admin. Perhaps he has no privs? And perhaps he does not want to get sys admin involved? But if this runs in an infinite loop, and checks every second, it will use lots of CPU, so the sys admin will know anyway. Also, depending on how long it runs, it could run thousands of times per day. This code only gives it a window in which to run -- it does not make sure it only runs once in the window.

Comment: but would this code execute the script once the time equals what is specified?

Comment: @BenThomson no. You have to manually execute the script once an hour, and it will execute **only** if the hour is in the specified range. See my answer on cron usage.

Comment: If you are not admin on the machine: each user can usually have its own crontab, accessed by running `crontab -e`. The format is the same, a part from you cannot specify an user to be used to execute the command. If you are using shared hosting, have a look at control panel; they usually have something to create cronjobs. If not, change hosting provider :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better way is to use cron. This is quite simple, although it may look intimidating at first:

### Step 1 - Create a script that will be run by cron

For example, place this in `<your-app-root>/cron.php`:

```
<?php
$CRON_KEY = "some-random-value-here";
if ($_GET['key'] != $CRON_KEY) {
    header(“HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden”);
    echo "You have no rights to access this page.";
    exit();
}

// Your code here
```

### Step 2 - Add crontab entry

To automatically execute your `cron.php` script, you can add a line like this to `/etc/crontab`:

```
## This will run each day at 2:30 AM
30 2    * * *   www-data    wget -O - -q http://yourdomain.com/cron.php?key=some-random-value-here &> /tmp/my-app-cron.log
```

..where `some-random-value-here` must match the random value placed in the PHP script. This is a security feature to prevent anybody from running your cron code.

#### Crontab line description

The first five parts of crontab line are: minutes, hours, day of month, month, day of week.

You can also use ranges, for example to run the script each day at 5, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20 you can use this:

```
0 5-8,12-15,20    * * *    ...
```

You can also use "steps", for example to run every 5 minutes (suggested for recurrent jobs, such as indexing / cleanup tasks, etc):

```
*/5 *    * * *    ...
```

The sixth argument is the user that will be used to execute the command. You can use whichever user you want here, www-data, nobody, your user, etc. Best practice is to never use root here, unless really needed for some reason.

The remaining part of the line is the command that will be run at scheduled time.

The `&> /tmp/my-app-cron.log` part will make all the output from your latest cron.php execution to be stored inside `/tmp/my-app-cron.log`.

### Read more..

For more information on cron usage, you can refer to `crontab(5)`:

```
$ man 5 crontab
```